# How can order the cursor by datetime and Integer

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying order the resulting cursor by DateTime first then an Integer ID.

If i order by DateTime alone it works fine and if i order by Integer ID alone, it works fine too.

What i have tried so far: I tried appending ASC to the Integer ID sort. (i know it is default but worth a try).

Can anybody shed any light why SQL will not order as i wish?

Here is my table creation:

```
String sqlToCreateUnallocatedCalls = String
                    .format("create table %s ( %s INTEGER primary key, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT" +
                                    ", %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s INTEGER, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT, %s TEXT)",
                            TABLEUNALLOCATEDCALLS, C_ID_UNALLOCATED_CALL, C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_CALLID,
                            C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_START_DATE, C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_END_DATE, C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_DURATION, C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_CLIENTID,
                            C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_CLIENTSURNAME, C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_CLIENTFORENAME, C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_CARERID, C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_CARERSURNAME,
                            C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_CARERFORENAME, C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_NEEDNAME, C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_RUNNAME, C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_RUNID,
                            C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_CARERAWAYREASON, C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_NOTES, C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_CLIENTKEYSAFE, C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_CLIENTENTRYMETHOD,
                            C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_ISHEADER, C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_ISDATEHEADER, C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_STARTTIME);

            db.execSQL(sqlToCreateUnallocatedCalls);
            Log.e(TAG, "onUpgrade " + sqlToCreateUnallocatedCalls);
```

I want to order by C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_STARTDATE, then by C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_RUNID.

startdate is TEXT and runid is Integer.

Here is my query:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLEUNALLOCATED_CALL + " where " + LoginValidate.C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_RUNID + " > 0 ORDER BY "
               + LoginValidate.C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_START_DATE + " DESC , " + LoginValidate.C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_RUNID + " ASC";

       Cursor c = nfcAppObj.getDb().rawQuery(sql, null);
```

Here is a screenshot of the results:
[image]

As you can see, the dates are in order but the runID are not. they should be eithe 4,12,12 or 12,12,4 not 12,4,12.

thanks

[EDIT1]

i have checked the cursor content directly after it return from DB and before it is passed back to cursorLoader.

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLEUNALLOCATED_CALL + " where " + LoginValidate.C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_RUNID + " > 0 ORDER BY "
               + LoginValidate.C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_START_DATE + " DESC , " + LoginValidate.C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_RUNID + " ASC";

       Cursor c = nfcAppObj.getDb().rawQuery(sql, null);


      if(c != null){

          if(c.moveToFirst()){

              do{

                  //String runid = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_RUNID));
                  int runid = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(LoginValidate.C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_RUNID));
                  Log.e(TAG, "runid = " + runid);

              }while(c.moveToNext());


          }
```

Results:

```
2021-04-28 13:15:22.547 794-7944/com.xxx.x E/RR3ContentProvider: runid = 12
2021-04-28 13:15:22.547 6794-7944/com.xxx.x\ E/RR3ContentProvider: runid = 4
2021-04-28 13:15:22.547 6794-7944/com.xxx.x E/RR3ContentProvider: runid = 12
2021-04-28 13:15:22.547 6794-7944/com.xxx.x E/RR3ContentProvider: runid = 11
```

[EDIT 2]

```
String selection = LoginValidate.C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_RUNID + " > 0 ";

            String sort = LoginValidate.C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_START_DATE + " ASC , " + LoginValidate.C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_RUNID;

            

            cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(this, RR3ContentProvider.CONTENT_URI_UNALLOCATEDCALLS, projection, selection, null,
                    sort );
```

Comment: What is the format of the dates in `C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_START_DATE`? Did you check the cursor object returned by rawQuery() if the rows are ordered properly before you display the results?

Comment: @forpas yes i have inspected the result of cursor directly from DB. I've posted EDIT1 above

Comment: @forpas the format of date is 2021-04-30T17:00:00

Comment: The format of your dates is fine and the sql select statement seems correct. Next step is to extract the db from the device and inspect it. Check the table definition is exactly as it is meant to be and the values of the 2 columns also. I can't reproduce your issue. Can you reproduce it with sample data in a fiddle: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27? Also double check all the `C_xxxxxx` constants that you use.

Comment: Is it possible that the `T` is missing in some of the dates?

Comment: @forpas I thought i'd mentioned in my OP that i'm using SqlCipher DB. Does that make a difference and could i still extract and inspect?

Comment: @forpas also i am happy with how sql is displaying the dateTrime, it seem in order. What should happen is, say i have 4 rows with today's date and 4 rows with tomorrow's date, it will show all today's, then tomorrow's should be the last 4 in the list.(which it does. What is not happening is the runid should also be in order for each of the 4 rows for each day. sorry if you understand this already)

Comment: If you want to sort only by the date and not the time part of the datetime then you should use: `String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLEUNALLOCATED_CALL + " where " + LoginValidate.C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_RUNID + " > 0 ORDER BY DATE(" + LoginValidate.C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_START_DATE + ") DESC , " + LoginValidate.C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_RUNID + " ASC";`

Comment: @forpas :) Thankyou so much, it works now. I've been stuck on this for a week now, thinking it was sql engine problem or maybe linked with CursorLoader or contentProvider.. Can you put your cooment in an answer and i'll accept when eligible to do so. thankyou again

Comment: @forpas oh sorry i forgot to mention. The original call to the DB was from a Cursorloader via a contentProvider. how would i put your changes into the sort in EDIT 2?

Comment: @forpas like this?  String sort = "DATE(" + LoginValidate.C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_START_DATE + " ASC , " + LoginValidate.C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_RUNID + ")";

Comment: No, the parenteses must include only the datetime column. Like this: `String sort = "DATE(" + LoginValidate.C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_START_DATE + ") DESC, " + LoginValidate.C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_RUNID + " ASC";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column `LoginValidate.C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_START_DATE` contains both the date and the time.
If you want to sort only by the date part use the function `DATE()`:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLEUNALLOCATED_CALL + " where " + 
            LoginValidate.C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_RUNID + " > 0 ORDER BY DATE(" +                        
            LoginValidate.C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_START_DATE + ") DESC, " +             
            LoginValidate.C_UNALLOCATED_CALL_RUNID + " ASC";
```

Comment: sorry forgot all about this :)